# Why is the extern func called multiple times?

Tags: halide

Recently, I tried using the defin_extern method defined by Halide with AOT mode.
The description code of the Halide frontend is as follows:

```
class ExternFuncInput : public Generator<ExternFuncInput> {
    Input<Buffer<int>> input{"input", 2};
    Input<int> addend{"addend"};
    Output<Buffer<int>> output{"output", 2};
    Func input_ub{"input_ub"}; 
    Func work{"work"}; 
    Func extern_func{"extern_func"};
    Func vmuls{"vmuls"};
    Var x{"x"}, y{"y"};

public:
    void generate() {
        input_ub(x, y) = input(x, y);
        work(x, y) = input_ub(x, y) * 2;
        std::vector<ExternFuncArgument> params = {addend};
        std::vector<Type> types = {Int(32)};
        std::vector<Var> args = {x, y};
        extern_func.define_extern("extern_stage", params, types, args, NameMangling::Default, DeviceAPI::CUDA);
        vmuls(x, y) = extern_func(x, y) * 3;
        output(x, y) = vmuls(x, y) + work(x, y);
    }

    void schedule() {
        Var xo, yo, xi, yi;
        // output.tile(x, y, xo, yo, xi, yi, 128, 128);
        output.split(x, xo, xi, 128);
        output.split(y, yo, yi, 128);
        output.reorder(xi, yi, xo, yo);
        input_ub.compute_at(output, xo);   
        work.compute_at(output, xo).vectorize(x, 32);
        extern_func.compute_root();
        vmuls.compute_at(output, xo).vectorize(x, 32);
        output.compute_root().vectorize(xi, 32);
    }
};
```

After Unrolling Pass, the IR are as follows:

```
Lowering after simplifying correlated differences:
assert((call)(uint64)reinterpret((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer) != (uint64)0, (call)halide_error_buffer_argument_is_null("output"))
assert((call)(uint64)reinterpret((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer) != (uint64)0, (call)halide_error_buffer_argument_is_null("input"))
let input = (call)(void *)_halide_buffer_get_host((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer)
let input.type = (call)(uint32)_halide_buffer_get_type((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer)
let input.dimensions = (call)_halide_buffer_get_dimensions((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer)
let input.min.0 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_min((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer, 0)
let input.extent.0 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_extent((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer, 0)
let input.stride.0 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_stride((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer, 0)
let input.min.1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_min((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer, 1)
let input.extent.1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_extent((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer, 1)
let input.stride.1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_stride((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)input.buffer, 1)
let output = (call)(void *)_halide_buffer_get_host((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer)
let output.type = (call)(uint32)_halide_buffer_get_type((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer)
let output.dimensions = (call)_halide_buffer_get_dimensions((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer)
let output.min.0 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_min((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer, 0)
let output.extent.0 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_extent((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer, 0)
let output.stride.0 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_stride((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer, 0)
let output.min.1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_min((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer, 1)
let output.extent.1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_extent((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer, 1)
let output.stride.1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_stride((Variable)(halide_buffer_t *)output.buffer, 1)
let extern_func.o0.bounds_query = let t3 = (call)(halide_dimension_t *)make_struct((Variable)output.min.0, (Variable)output.extent.0, 0, 0, (Variable)output.min.1, (Variable)output.extent.1, 0, 0) in (call)(halide_buffer_t *)_halide_buffer_init((call)(halide_buffer_t *)alloca((call)size_of_halide_buffer_t()), (Variable)t3, (call)(void *)reinterpret((uint64)0), (uint64)0, (call)(halide_device_interface_t *)reinterpret((uint64)0), 0, 32, 2, (Variable)t3, (uint64)0)
let t4 = (call)extern_stage((Variable)addend, (Variable)extern_func.o0.bounds_query)
assert((Variable)t4 == 0, (call)halide_error_bounds_inference_call_failed("extern_stage", (Variable)t4))
let extern_func.s0.y.min_1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_min((Variable)extern_func.o0.bounds_query, 1)
let extern_func.s0.y.max_1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_max((Variable)extern_func.o0.bounds_query, 1)
let extern_func.s0.x.min_1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_min((Variable)extern_func.o0.bounds_query, 0)
let extern_func.s0.x.max_1 = (call)_halide_buffer_get_max((Variable)extern_func.o0.bounds_query, 0)
let extern_func.o0.bounds_query_1 = let t1 = (call)(halide_dimension_t *)make_struct((Variable)extern_func.s0.x.min_1, (add)(sub)((Variable)extern_func.s0.x.max_1 - (Variable)extern_func.s0.x.min_1) + 1, 0, 0, (Variable)extern_func.s0.y.min_1, (add)(sub)((Variable)extern_func.s0.y.max_1 - (Variable)extern_func.s0.y.min_1) + 1, 0, 0) in (call)(halide_buffer_t *)_halide_buffer_init((call)(halide_buffer_t *)alloca((call)size_of_halide_buffer_t()), (Variable)t1, (call)(void *)reinterpret((uint64)0), (uint64)0, (call)(halide_device_interface_t *)reinterpret((uint64)0), 0, 32, 2, (Variable)t1, (uint64)0)
let t2 = (call)extern_stage((Variable)addend, (Variable)extern_func.o0.bounds_query_1)
assert((Variable)t2 == 0, (call)halide_error_bounds_inference_call_failed("extern_stage", (Variable)t2))
let input.extent.0.required.s = (sub)min((mul)(div)((add)((Variable)output.extent.0 + -1)/128)*128, (add)(Variable)output.extent.0 + -128) - min((Variable)output.extent.0, 128)
let input.extent.1.required.s = (sub)min((mul)(div)((add)((Variable)output.extent.1 + -1)/128)*128, (add)(Variable)output.extent.1 + -128) - min((Variable)output.extent.1, 128)
let output.extent.0.required.s = (Variable)input.extent.0.required.s
let output.extent.1.required.s = (Variable)input.extent.1.required.s
...
...
allocate extern_func[...]
(ProducerConsumer)produce extern_func {
  let halide_device_malloc_result = (call)halide_device_malloc((Variable)extern_func.buffer, (call)(halide_device_interface_t *)halide_cuda_device_interface())
  assert((Variable)halide_device_malloc_result == 0, (Variable)halide_device_malloc_result)
  let t0 = (call)extern_stage((Variable)addend, (Variable)extern_func.buffer)
  assert((Variable)t0 == 0, (call)halide_error_extern_stage_failed("extern_stage", (Variable)t0))
  (evaluate)(call)_halide_buffer_set_device_dirty((Variable)extern_func.buffer, (uint1)1)
 }
```

My question is :
Why is extern_stage called multiple times before extern_stage is generated? Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's performing some *bounds queries* to determine sizes for intermediate buffers. Halide has to call the function at runtime to get the necessary bounds information. It's a required part of the extern func interface.

There are several examples of extern funcs in our tests:

- https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/extern_bounds_inference.cpp
- https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/extern_sort.cpp
- https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/generator/extern_output_generator.cpp

If you have a simple bounds relationship, it might be possible to provide a bounds *proxy* expression, which Halide will use for bounds inference instead of calling your extern func. Here's an example: https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/src/autoschedulers/adams2019/test_function_dag.cpp